# Terminal doesn't close with "exit" command after upgrade to 14.10

Tags: 14.04, command-line, upgrade

Upgrading from Ubuntu 14.04LTS to Ubuntu 14.10, the upgrade seems to work OK but using "exit" in gnome terminal just prints exit on the next line and comes back with the command line prompt. This didn't happen before, the terminal would just close (as I expected). I noted the Ubuntu Releases Index page on the web only seems to list Ubuntu Server, has the Desktop not been released yet or have both been combined as I wonder if the gnome terminal on the server release does this as it doesn't have a GUI.

Answer (score 4):

Enter the terminal and select Edit and select Profile Preferences for the menu, then select the Title and Command and in "When command exits: select the "Exit terminal" option.