# 'exit' command not working anymore

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, bashrc

I was trying to install certain software and edited bashrc file, due to various errors I replaced it with default basrc file, but now 'exit' command is not exiting the terminal, its simply displaying 'exit'. can i get back the exit command?

Comment: It sounds like you may be more than one shell deep in your terminal - if you open a new terminal, what is the output of `echo $SHLVL` ?

Comment: Check [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/546826/terminal-doesnt-close-with-exit-command-after-upgrade-to-14-10). Note that if you are using another terminal emulator different than gnome-terminal, this setting could be in another place.

Comment: @steeldriver echo $SHLVL is returining '1'

Comment: @ImADrafter thank you for the help. your solution worked